# Equivalent of C++ "this" pointer in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, this

I'm trying to translate a successfully working C++ program to C# and I'm currently stuck at initializing the audio output device. I would like to know the equivalent of 'this' pointer in C#.

Below is the working C++ code:

```
DWORD WINAPI SCFStartOutSound(SCFHANDLE sohOwnerHandle, SCFHANDLE *pscfHandle, SCFEventOutSoundCallback lpfnEventCallback, BSTR FileName);

CCComBSTR FileName = "Out_DxSpeaker.dll";
HANDLE OutSoundHandle = NULL;
SCFStartOutSound(this, &OutSoundHandle, OnSCFEventOutSoundCallback, FileName);
```

Class:

```
CTestAppDlg::CTestAppDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
: CDialog(CTestAppDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);

}
```

Typedef:

```
typedef HANDLE SCFHANDLE;
```

Result: The audio output device is properly initialized

[Initialized output device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yx8qP.png)

Now here is the my C# translated code:

```
[DllImport(DllFileName.dll)]
unsafe public static extern uint SCFStartOutSound(IntPtr OwnerHandle,IntPtr* soundoutHandle, SCFEventOutSoundCallback EventCallback, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string fileName);

  unsafe
    {
        IntPtr soundOutPtr;
        uint res = SCFStartOutSound(this.Handle, &soundOutPtr, onSoundOutEventCallback,"Out_DxSpeaker.dll");
        MessageBox.Show(res.ToString());
    }
```

This code results to a System.AccessViolationException.

I know that 'this' in C++ is a pointer that holds the memory address of the current object while 'this' in C# refers to the current instance of the class .

Comment: Some projects needs to allow Unsafe Code in compilation options

Comment: Unsafe code was already enabled sir.

Comment: how does `this` qualify as `SCFHANDLE` in the original? (typedef of `SCFHANDLE`, class declaration of which `this` is an instance in the original?) do you also have the source code of `SCFStartOutSound` so you would know what properties it expects from the `OwnerHandle` argument?

Comment: sir @dlatikay I edited the post,information about the class and typedef was added.

Comment: LoadIcon() is returning an ICON which contains a handle which is a 32 bit number.   So you need to pass the handle from LocaIcon().